# why is query getting records which are not part of where clause?

Tags: sql

I have a query

```
  select account, collateral,rest_flag_11 ,member_rest_flag11,member_rest_flag12
   from FileDaily
  left join member
  on member.member_account=FileDaily.account
  where member.member_rest_flag11= 80 or member.member_rest_flag12=80
  and FileDaily.REST_FLAG_11=0 and FileDaily.COLLATERAL in (10,11,13,20)
```

It's getting records where collateral=30,40
which are not part of the collateral in (10,11,13,20),
why would this be?

I'm trying to ge tthe account number where in filedaily table  collateral=(10,,11,13,20) 
and rest_flag_11=0 and in the member the member_account is member_rest_flag_11=80 and member_rest_flag12=80.

I use sql server 2012.

Comment: Because you are using an `OR` without considering the correct logic

Comment: you're mixing `and` and `or` clauses. they have different binding precedences and your query is running in a way different than what you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is presumably parentheses, which you can fix by doing this:

```
where (member.member_rest_flag11= 80 or member.member_rest_flag12=80) and
     FileDaily.REST_FLAG_11=0 and FileDaily.COLLATERAL in (10,11,13,20)
```

You can rewrite this using `in`:

```
where 80 in (member.member_rest_flag11, member.member_rest_flag12) and
      FileDaily.REST_FLAG_11 = 0 and
      FileDaily.COLLATERAL in (10, 11, 13, 20)
```

I would also recommend that you use table abbreviations for table aliases.  They make queries easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 1):

You miss parenthesis

```
select account, collateral,rest_flag_11 ,member_rest_flag11,member_rest_flag12
  from FileDaily
left join member
on member.member_account=FileDaily.account
where (member.member_rest_flag11= 80 or member.member_rest_flag12=80)
and FileDaily.REST_FLAG_11=0 and FileDaily.COLLATERAL in (10,11,13,20)
```